# Upload File Server PHP

Tags: php, mysql, formularios, archivo, servidor

Tengo que subir 2 imágenes. Una es una imagen de producto y otra de un QR. Ademas el código quiero que inserte en una base de datos MySQL la URL de cada imagen.
He conseguido que la URL de cada imagen se registre en la base de datos y que se suba una de las dos imágenes, pero la imagen que corresponde al código QR no queda en el servidor solo la primera, no recibo ningún mensaje de error.

Esta es la tabla en MySql
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La imagen de producto es "product_image" y la del código QR es product_qr

Esto es el "interface" de usuario creado con "modal" en PHP-
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
A continuación pongo el trozo de código que corresponde a la función que conecta con la base de datos y que se encarga de subir los archivos:

```
$type = explode('.', $_FILES['productImage']['name']);
$type = $type[count($type)-1];
$typeQR = explode('.', $_FILES['productQR']['name']);
$typeQR = $typeQR[count($typeQR)-1];


$url = '../assests/images/stock/'.uniqid(rand()).'.'.$type;
$urlQR = '../assests/images/stock/'.uniqid(rand()).'.'.$typeQR;

if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG')) ||
in_array($typeQR, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG')) ) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name']) ||
    is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name']) ) {
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) ||
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR)) {

            $sql = "INSERT INTO product (product_name, product_image, brand_id, categories_id, quantity,
            rate, active, status, description, position_store, status_product, reference, product_qr)
            VALUES ('$productName', '$url', '$brandName', '$categoryName', '$quantity', '$rate',
             '$productStatus', 1, '$productDescription', '$positionStore', '$statusObject', '$reference', '$urlQR')";
```

Este es el códgo del "modal":

```
<div class="modal-body" style="max-height:450px; overflow:auto;">

        <div id="add-product-messages"></div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productImage" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Imagen: </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <!-- the avatar markup -->
                        <div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="display:none;"></div>
                    <div class="kv-avatar center-block">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="productImage" placeholder="Imagen del producto" name="productImage" class="file-loading" style="width:auto;"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="productQR" class="col-sm-3 control-label">QR: </label>
            <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <!-- the avatar markup -->
                        <div id="kv-avatar-errors-1" class="center-block" style="display:none;"></div>
                    <div class="kv-avatar center-block">
                        <input type="file" class="form-control" id="productQR" placeholder="Imagen QR" name="productQR" class="file-loading" style="width:auto;"/>
                    </div>

                </div>
        </div>
        Y>
```

Como digo, todo funciona bien, pro la imagen del QR no sube al servidor.

Comment: creo que en tu HTML debes declarar el tipo File como un array es decir,
type="file[]", pero seria ideal ver el contenido que llega a tu php, podrías imprimir el arreglo completo y verificar si llegan los dos input.

Comment: Pero entonces por qué sí sube un archivo y el otro no? Si es ese el error, no debería subir ninguna de las dos imágenes, en mi caso solo sube la primera. Creo que el error parte de cómo estoy subiendo los dos archivos, creo que es ese el error, que la construcción no es la correcta. Mi duda es como puedo subir dos archivos al mismo tiempo dentro de mi programa.

Comment: estimado, es por eso que le pedia ver el contenido total del array file... para ver si existen los dos indices e para ir aclarando mas el problema... eso...

espero soluciones tu problema :)  saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estaba subiendo las dos imágenes (Archivos) porque en la expresión "in_array" estaba usando "o" --> "||". Para que funcione se debe declarar "y" --> "&&". Por tanto el código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
    if(in_array($type, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG')) && in_array($typeQR, array('gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'JPG', 'GIF', 'JPEG', 'PNG')) ) {
    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name']) ) {          
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImage']['tmp_name'], $url) && move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productQR']['tmp_name'], $urlQR)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomiendo que utilices el framework arcaela, está en Github
https://github.com/arcaelas/arc Tiene en sus clases una llamada fileManager();
Te permite subir ficheros sin tantas complicaciones, solo llamas la clase así:

```
//Abres el Object
$files = new fileManager();

//No te preocupes si es $_FILES o es Base64 o es un link de una imagen,
//La funcion lo detecta y hace lo que deba hacer para crear la imagen.
$files = $files->addFiles($_FILES['nombre_del_input']);

//Indicas el fichero
$files = $files->setDir("/ruta/donde/subirás_el_archivo/");

//Inicias el upload
$files = $files->start();
```

Te devolverá un array con 3 valores, Wait, Error y Success, en el wait están los ficheros que eseperan para subirse, los demás creo que los entiendes.
Si necesitas cancelar la operación solo llamas $files->abort();

Cuando los ficheros se cargan correctamente te devuelven un array cada uno con el nombre, la ruta y fecha.
Ya con esos valores creo que puedes trabajar en el MySql.

Cabe destacar que ese sistema de arc está en desarrollo pero ví que en BitBucket actualizan constantemente, solo que liberan al público muy pocas veces.